# How to increase the size of the mode-line

Tags: mode-line

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vdOrsywra0) video on someone's emacs configuration, and I noticed that his mode line seemed a lot better to look at than mine, but he didn't explain it in the video.  Is there a way to replicate the mode line in the video, or to remove the parentheses around the mode and increase the size of the status line?  Or is it some plugin.  Ive already tried all the themes in the powerline and smart mode line plugins, and I can't seem to find a way to replicate it.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Because different components of the mode-line can have different faces and sizes, there is one general rule.  However. you can start by typing `M-x customize-face RET mode-line RET` and set the `:height` property to something like `140` or whatever floats your boat.  And, then do the same thing for `mode-line-inactive`.

Comment: that seems to change the size of the text and the mode-line, is there a way to change the text bask to normal size, but keep the height of the mode line? It also seems like the text is centered at the bottom, is there any way to center it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `mode-line` with a `:box` property which has a greater `line-width`. The thing is you must set the `:background` to have the same color as the `:color` of the `:box`.

I use this in my theme:

```
`(mode-line ((t (:background "black" :foreground "gray70" :box (:line-width 4 :color "black")))))
```

Or you can set `mode-line` in your .init file

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(mode-line ((t (:background "black" :foreground "gray70" :box (:line-width 4 :color "black"))))))
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: Well, the code didn't work, but I was able to do  the same thing with the customization menu.  Maybe its cause i'm on a mac.

Comment: It doesn't work because that was supposed to be added to the theme file. I have updated the anaswer.